# Window trigger function doesn't work in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have a made a sidebar with a toggle function in jquery. This is my function:

```
 function toggle() {
     var $btn = $(".sidebarToggle");
     var $budget = $(".budget");
     if ($budget.hasClass("sidebarHidden")) {
        $btn.find("i").removeClass("fa-caret-right").addClass("fa-caret-left");
        $budget.removeClass("sidebarHidden");
     } else {
        $btn.find("i").removeClass("fa-caret-left").addClass("fa-caret-right");
        $budget.addClass("sidebarHidden");
     }
     $(window).trigger('resize');
  }
```

And this is my HTML5 code:

```
 <div class="sidebar sidebar-hastopnav autoscroll">     
  <div class="sidebarToggle" ng-click="vm.toggle()"><i class="fa fa fa-caret-left"></i></div>
```

The problem is when I click on the class it wont fire the `$(window).trigger('resize');` function and it doesn't resize. I already check the other stackoverflow post like: [jQuery resize event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683377/jquery-resize-event-not-firing)

And

[$(window).resize() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947287/window-resize-not-working)

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards.

Update:

[image: Sketch]

Comment: have you tried adding a resize event on the window to see if it is triggered or not? do `$(window).on('resize', function(){console.log('Resize event fired!');});`

Comment: Hi @antoni thank you for your time. I just copied your code and I openend google dev. The console log doesn't show in the console log. I don't think it's not triggered.

Comment: Can you do the same and resize browser manually to make sure the window is bindable in your code? you should then see the alert

Comment: *"and it doesn't resize"* The `resize` event is ... an **event**.  ie it fires when the window resizes, it's not a command to "change the size of the window".  it's re-active, not pro-active.   [unless I'm mis-reading the context and "it" referes to something else and not the window]

Comment: Do you have any code to listen to the window resize event?  It's not included in the question.

Comment: @freedomn-m, you are right. but you can still trigger the event if you have a binded event on it (in this case i understand user wants to trigger the function associated to a resize event of a third party lib sidebar or whatever)

Comment: @antoni interesting - where did you get 'third party lib sidebar'?  and how does OP know the event is not firing?

Comment: @Fearhunter how do you know the event is not firing?   Fiddle showing event firing on button click: https://jsfiddle.net/fbbsp262/

Comment: I made a sketch. When I resize the window manually it does trigger the event. But it must trigger when I click on the arrow.

Comment: Can you include the basic (not complete) code for the event?  Specifically how it's wired up.

Comment: I notice you use Angular, you should add the tag in case someone knows about a module that does it

Comment: `$(window).resize()` resizes your browser window not what's inside e.g. `'div` of sidebar and main-space. You need to resize `div` size using plaing jquery or angular(i am not aware of)

Answer (score 0):

You can try alternative solutions provided in this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript) blog post on - **Window Resize**.

Hope this helps you. Thanks.